# jquery pan zoom not working inside colorbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have used jquery panzoom extracted from this site `https://github.com/timmywil/jquery.panzoom` inside the color box. The zoom option doesn't work inside the color box. If i placed it outside the popup it works fine. How to fix this?

Internal Script:

```
<script>
      $("#panzoom").panzoom({
        $zoomIn: $(".zoom-in"),
        $zoomOut: $(".zoom-out"),
        $zoomRange: $(".zoom-range"),
        $reset: $(".reset")
      });
    </script>
```

Html:

```
<section>
        <div id="panzoom" style="text-align: center">
        <img src="http://blog.millermedeiros.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/04/awesome_tiger.svg" width="300" height="300">
      </div>
    </section>
      <button class="zoom-in">Zoom In</button>
      <button class="zoom-out">Zoom Out</button>
      <input type="range" class="zoom-range">
      <button class="reset">Reset</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('selector').colorbox(inline:true,onComplete:function(){
$("#panzoom").panzoom({
        $zoomIn: $(".zoom-in"),
        $zoomOut: $(".zoom-out"),
        $zoomRange: $(".zoom-range"),
        $reset: $(".reset")
      });

}
});
```